# Is using the RequestHandlerComponent in a model possible?

Tags: cakephp, requesthandler

I'm new to PHP and decided to use the cakePHP framework to help me get started.

I can't figure out one thing though, I want to call methods on the RequestHandlerComponent class to update a users last used IP address and other information, I figured the best place to put this would be in the beforeSave() method on the User model.

I can't figure out how to call the getClientIP method though.

The normal code that would otherwise go in the controller doesn't work. Is there another way to call this class if you're in the model and not the controller?

Class Level:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

And in the function:

```
$this->data['User']['lastActiveIP'] = $this->RequestHandler->getClientIP();
```

Gives:

```
Undefined property: User::$RequestHandler
Call to a member function getClientIP() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components, by design, aren't available to models (without bypassing MVC convention - which you can do, of course). If you chose to force it to be available, look into `ClassRegistry::init()`. A better solution, I think, would be to employ the `RequestHandler` component in your controller (where it's meant to be used), set the `lastActiveIp` value in the controller (exactly as you've shown in your own example code) and pass the entire data array along to the model.

Now your component is being used where it should be and the model gets to remain ignorant about *where* it gets its data. At the risk of oversimplification, all the model should know is what to do with the data once it arrives; let the controller worry about collecting and packaging the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't consider I was violating MVC convention when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rob's answer, maybe it's enough to put a bit of code together yourself that uses the general `env('REMOTE_ADDR')` or similar variables. Look at the `RequestHandler` code, it's not doing anything terrifically complicated.

You may even be able to call the component statically, which is slightly better than instantiating it in the model (still in violation of MVC though). Untested, but should work:

```
App::import('Component', 'RequestHandler');
RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIp();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but since I seem to be breaking MVC convention, its probably better I do this in the controller anyways.